# How to format a duration

Tags: go

I have the following code which I can't run on play because I use the gin framework and filewalk.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "time"
    "regexp"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "sort"
    "strings"
    "github.com/davidscholberg/go-durationfmt"
)

var filext = regexp.MustCompile(`\.[mM][pP]4|\.[mM]4[vV]|\.jpg|\.[hH]264|\.go`)
var m map[int]string
var keys []int

func main() {

    if gin.IsDebugging() {
        fmt.Print("This progamm shows only the path and the age of a file in 'STARTDIR'\n")
        fmt.Print("only the following files will be handled '.[mM][pP]4|.[mM]4[vV$|.[hH]264|.go'\n")
        fmt.Print("The git repository: https://gitlab.com/aleks001/show-files-age \n")
    }

    if len(os.Getenv("LISTEN_IP_PORT")) == 0 {
        fmt.Print("I need a ip and port on which I should listen.\n")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    router := gin.Default()

    gin.DisableConsoleColor()

    router.GET("/videoinfo",getInfo)

    router.Run(os.Getenv("LISTEN_IP_PORT"))
}

func getInfo(c *gin.Context)  {

    loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("Europe/Vienna")
    var startdir = ""

    if os.Getenv("STARTDIR") != "" {
        startdir = os.Getenv("STARTDIR")
    } else if c.GetHeader("STARTDIR") != "" {
        startdir = c.GetHeader("STARTDIR")
    } else {
        c.String(404,"Startdir not found <br>\n")
        return
    }

    m = make(map[int]string)
    keys = nil

    filepath.Walk(startdir,walkpath)

    for k := range m {
        keys = append(keys, k)
    }
    sort.Ints(keys)

    for _, k := range keys {
        t := time.Date(time.Now().Year(),time.Now().Month(),time.Now().Day(),time.Now().Hour(),k,time.Now().Second(),time.Now().Nanosecond(),loc)
        durStr, err := durationfmt.Format(time.Since(t), "%h:%m")

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        } else {
            //fmt.Println(durStr)
            fmt.Printf("Key: %s Value: %s\n", durStr , m[k])
            c.String(200,"Minutes: %s File: %s\n", durStr, m[k])
        }
    }
}

func walkpath(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {

  if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        if filext.MatchString(path) {
            age := time.Now().Sub(f.ModTime())
            path_new := strings.Replace(path,"/videos/","",1)
            // path_new := strings.Replace(path,"..\\","",1)
            /*
            fmt.Printf("Path: %s, ModTime: %s, Age: %s <br>\n", walker.Path(), walker.Stat().ModTime(), age)
            c.String(200,"Path: %s, ModTime: %s, Age: %s <br>\n", walker.Path(), walker.Stat().ModTime(), age)
            */
            fmt.Printf("Path: %s, Age: %d age minutes %0.2f  <br>\n", path_new, age, age.Minutes())
            m[int(age.Minutes())]=path_new
            //c.String(200,"Path: %s, Age: %0.2f <br>\n", path, age.Minutes())
        }
    //fmt.Printf("%s with %d bytes at motime %s\n", path,f.Size(), f.ModTime())
}
    return nil
}
```

What I want to do is a sorted output of files based on `filext` als filter and the modtime as sort criteria.

I was able to fulfil the most part of the request but the output looks ugly as you can see below.

I have used https://github.com/davidscholberg/go-durationfmt to format the duration but the output looks ugly or I missus the library.

```
Minutes: 0:6 File: upload/dir003/file1.m4v
Minutes: 0:5 File: transfer/dir5/file2.jpg
Minutes: -5:-48 File: transfer/dir001/file.mp4
Minutes: -6:-21 File: transfer/03.jpg
Minutes: -6:-22 File: transfer/02.mp4
```

Comment: Does the default duration format not work for you?

Comment: No this is much much uglier it uses 6 fractional digits and I only need 2 the output should looks like HH:SS

Comment: Can you then show exactly what you want? `time.Duration` has `Hours`, `Minutes` and `Seconds` methods to give you the numeric values to format however you need.

Comment: I have a int which is `f os.FileInfo ; age := time.Now().Sub(f.ModTime()); age.Minutes()` and this int value must be formated. I will paste the code into the question

Comment: If it has too large a fractional portion, just use `Duration.Round()` to round it as necessary, e.g. `age.Round(time.Second)`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For example, to provide a custom format for a duration,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func fmtDuration(d time.Duration) string {
    d = d.Round(time.Minute)
    h := d / time.Hour
    d -= h * time.Hour
    m := d / time.Minute
    return fmt.Sprintf("%02d:%02d", h, m)
}

func main() {
    modTime := time.Now().Round(0).Add(-(3600 + 60 + 45) * time.Second)
    since := time.Since(modTime)
    fmt.Println(since)
    durStr := fmtDuration(since)
    fmt.Println(durStr)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/HT4bFfoA5r

Output:

```
1h1m45s
01:02
```

---

If you want to sort on a duration then use the Go [`sort`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/) package. I would sort on `ModTime` to defer the calculation of the duration, `Since(ModTime)`, to be accurate at the time it is printed. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "sort"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func isVideo(path string) bool {
    videos := []string{".mp4", ".m4v", ".h264"}
    ext := strings.ToLower(filepath.Ext(path))
    for _, video := range videos {
        if ext == video {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

type modTimeInfo struct {
    path    string
    modTime time.Time
}

func walkModTime(root string) ([]modTimeInfo, error) {
    var infos []modTimeInfo
    err := filepath.Walk(
        root,
        func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            if info.Mode().IsRegular() {
                path = filepath.Clean(path)
                if !isVideo(path) {
                    return nil
                }
                sep := string(filepath.Separator)
                dir := sep + `Videos` + sep
                path = strings.Replace(path, dir, sep, 1)
                infos = append(infos, modTimeInfo{
                    path:    path,
                    modTime: info.ModTime()},
                )
            }
            return nil
        },
    )
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return infos, nil
}

func sortModTime(infos []modTimeInfo) {
    sort.SliceStable(
        infos,
        func(i, j int) bool {
            return infos[i].modTime.Before(infos[j].modTime)
        },
    )
}

func fmtAge(d time.Duration) string {
    d = d.Round(time.Minute)
    h := d / time.Hour
    d -= h * time.Hour
    m := d / time.Minute
    return fmt.Sprintf("%02d:%02d", h, m)
}

func main() {
    root := `/home/peter/Videos` // Testing ...
    infos, err := walkModTime(root)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    sortModTime(infos)
    now := time.Now()
    for _, info := range infos {
        age := fmtAge(now.Sub(info.modTime))
        fmt.Println("Age (H:M):", age, "File:", info.path)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/j2TUmJdAi4

Comment: Thanks. it works for duration. I haven't found a sort.Duration(k) function, therefore I can't use it for `var keys []int` which is the key index for `m[int(age.Minutes())]=path_new`. I use this for sorting `sort.Ints(keys)`.  is there a sort.Duration() function?

Comment: @Aleksandar: See my revised answer.

Comment: Works well but only for positive durations

Comment: Isn't it smarter to use modulus instead of subtraction + multiplication of the previous operation to get it down to the number of minutes in the duration?

Answer (score 100):

FYI, if you just want to quickly display a duration, the built-in formatting works well:

```
fmt.Sprintf("duration: %s", d)
```

will display something like this:

```
duration: 7h3m45s
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer honestly

Comment: The problem with this is the oh-so-many digits after the decimal point. Example: `1m12.841086584s` But it's the obvious choice in general.

Comment: @rfay You can use `duration.Round(time.Second)`

Comment: Are you supposed to wrap fmt.Sprintf() inside a Print statement?

Answer (score 8):

Another way to format the duration if you don't care about the day, month or year

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Timespan time.Duration

func (t Timespan) Format(format string) string {
    return time.Unix(0, 0).UTC().Add(time.Duration(t)).Format(format)
}

func main() {
    dur := 7777 * time.Second
    fmt.Println(Timespan(dur).Format("15:04:05")) // 02:09:37
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/XM-884oYMvE

Comment: If you want the output to include milliseconds:
dur, _ := time.ParseDuration("2h9m37.6s")
fmt.Println(Timespan(dur).Format("15:04:05.000")) // 02:09:37.600

Comment: I like this approach the best. Since we can use the [time format](https://pkg.go.dev/time#pkg-constants), it is more flexible.

Answer (score 6):

Another easy way is to use the built in `time.Duration` [String function](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Duration.String).

```
duration.String()
```

Output: `28m26.550805438s`

Or to round the seconds first

```
duration.Round(time.Second).String()
```

Output: `28m27s`

Answer (score 2):

Format yourself.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    d := 7777 * time.Second

    hour := int(d.Hours())
    minute := int(d.Minutes()) % 60
    second := int(d.Seconds()) % 60
    fmt.Printf("%02d:%02d:%02d\n", hour, minute, second) // 02:09:37
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/AWWZ4YBMTGQ

Comment: thank you so much!! I wanna formatting HH:MM:DD, this answer fits to my problem